# What is the point of using the front-page.php template?

Tags: theme-development, themes, templates, page-template

You can use **front-page.php** to create a static front page, it will override all other templates and static front page settings, but the problem is that you can't edit the front page then.

You can't edit the front page from inside WordPress, and add content to it, like you can with pages.

If I choose to create a new page and use it as the static front page from the reading options in WordPress, I am able to edit this page.

[image]

The point of a CMS system is to make it easy to manipulate content, using **front-page.php** I have to edit the code directly.

So why should I use **front-page.php** instead of adding a page and setting it to be the static front page in reading options?

Comment: Depends what you are trying to accomplish. I use front-page.php with Advanced Custom Fields, which allows me to still manage some of the homepage content within WP on an options page, while automatically displaying custom loops of various information in other spots on the homepage. If you're truly just trying to set up a static homepage, using a Page is preferable as you can use the Editor like you said. But for something partially dynamic, partially static, front-page.php is a useful tool.

Comment: @rarst once mentioned that front-page.php is suitable for private project that need a static custom homepage, that is not like going to be changed. Not suitable for most of the public projects.

Comment: @WebElaine Thanks for the info, I learned something new.

Comment: @JackJohansson I was thinking the same thing, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the `front-page.php` template because it allows to have custom content and layout for your website's static front page.

You can edit content on your static front page from inside the WordPress admin if the `front-page.php` template contains the `the_content()` template tag or similar.

It really depends on what your content and presentation requirements are for your static homepage. Leaving out the `front-page.php` might be enough if you have basic content and presentation requirements. If your content and presentation requirements are more complex you might need to code or find a theme with a `front-page.php` template that better suits your needs.